# Report generator options for a Winforms app?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reporting

I’m selecting a report generator for my .NET winforms app and it’s driving me crazy. I’m not familiar at all with report generators so…

Does anyone knows of a report generator that:

1.- Is easy to deploy in relation to the main app

> a. (Least, least, least desirable)
>   Have a separate *scriptable/silent* installer
>   (I can make the app installer call the
>   report generator installer)
>
> b. (I can live with this) Have an
>   “integrable” installer (An integrated
>   installer for both the App and the
>   report generator can be made easily)
>
> c. (Most desirable) Clickonce/xcopy
>   installation possible (no installer at
>   all!!! yay!!!!).

2.- Is scriptable to some degree:

> a.    (I can live with this) Is it
>   possible to change certain properties
>   (image sources, colors, visibility,
>   widths, etc.) at runtime?
>
> b.    (Most
>   desirable) Is it possible –in addition
>   to the previous item- to add/remove
>   elements to the report at runtime?

3.- Self-adjusts when you resize the page:

> a. (Least desirable) You have to
>   manually resize things dynamically
>   accessing the report structures
>   (related to 2a)
>
> b. (Most desirable) The report and its
>   elements adjust automatically to the
>   available canvas/paper size (as HTML
>   pages do, using percentages)

4.- The size of individual elements in the report grows/shrinks in accordance to the content displayed inside (elements could be grid’s columns):

> a.    (Least desirable) The element only
>   grows vertically to accommodate bigger
>   content (no clipping).
>
> b.    The size of the elements can be
>   self-adjusting to content (like a
>   <div> element). Columns in a grid for
>   example should grow/shrink according
>   to content (as in a HTML <table>
>   element without columns widths)

5.- It should be possible to export a report to at least excel and PDF.

6.- The report viewer should support languages other than English.

I don’t know if my needs are unrealistic, but report generators are not my thing, I’m at a loss here.

Anyone with experience on the field can give me any pointer in the right direction for me to investigate?

Comment: Scaling like HTML can only work with primitive reports. HTML use not percentages. It use a complex layouting algorithm. Most people will print to A4 or letter. Is a scaling/zooming not better? For example you have an image in your report. Should it cut the margin if you print on a smaller paper? I think zooming is the better solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use DevExpress' XtraReports which works in WinForms, ASP.NET, WPF and Silverlight.  It is fully featured and should be capable of most if not all of what you are wanting.  Find out more here:

http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/

Comment: I'll second this. I have used Crystal, SQL Reporting Services, and Access as reporting engines and consider the DevExpress Reports to be top notch and my choice of reporting engine.

Comment: Any requirement of the above not supported (of half supported)? 3? 4?

Comment: I believe all of your requirements are supported, but I am not a client rep for DevExpress so I won't guarantee it :)  Before purchasing, download a trial (they offer 60 days) and give it a go.  You can also ask them all of the above in their support forum (which is really great).  It's a fantastic product (as is most of their line), and their support is top notch.  It's also relatively cheap.

Comment: Is there any such software for small developers? DevExpress and CrystalReports are incredibly costly.

Answer (score 1):

I have been in your position many times (architecting a WinForms app with a reporting feature) and I think your best bet is, wait for it... [Crystal Reports](http://www.crystalreports.com/). It meets all the criteria you laid out but does have the caveat of a very large redistributable runtime. It also has a .NET SDK, an embeddable designer etc.

Comment: "a very large redistributable runtime" 1a? How about point 3 and 4?

Comment: "It meets all the criteria you laid out"